# Query on Wikibase:label REGEX & STRLEN

Tags: regex, sparql, strlen, wikidata

I'm new to SparkQL & wikidata and I'm trying to query the following:

- Male singers (artists/performers)
- Who are alive
- Given name = 6 characters
- Given name does NOT Contain ("e","i","u")

I'm having trouble with the Filters on Given names (I believe it's because they reference the "SERVICE wikibase:label"). I've tried using HAVING to no avail. Is the correct action to nest the query and filter on that or are there more elegant ways?

```sql
#-- Male artists
SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?givennameLabel (STRLEN(?givennameLabel)AS ?Namechars)
 ?mLabel ?plLabel WHERE {
 ?m wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
 ?m wdt:P21 wd:Q6581097.
 ?m wdt:P735 ?givenname.
 ?m wdt:P27 ?pl.
 ?m (wdt:P106/wdt:P279*) wd:Q483501.
 OPTIONAL { ?m wdt:P175 ?performer. }
 OPTIONAL {?m wdt:P570 ?d } 
 FILTER (!bound(?d))
 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
FILTER (!regex(?givennameLabel,"(e|i|u)")). #no records
FILTER (STRLEN(?givennameLabel) = 6)        #no records
} #HAVING (!regex(?givennameLabel,"(e|i|u)")) #returns "Bad aggregate"
LIMIT 50
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Male%20artists%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fm%20%3FgivennameLabel%20%28STRLEN%28%3FgivennameLabel%29AS%20%3FNamechars%29%20%3FmLabel%20%3FplLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fm%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20%3Fm%20wdt%3AP21%20wd%3AQ6581097.%0A%20%20%3Fm%20wdt%3AP735%20%3Fgivenname.%0A%20%20%3Fm%20wdt%3AP27%20%3Fpl.%0A%20%20%3Fm%20%28wdt%3AP106%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%29%20wd%3AQ483501.%0A%20%20%23%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fm.%20%20%0A%20%20%23%3Farticle%20wd%3AP1661%20%3Frank.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fm%20wdt%3AP175%20%3Fperformer.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fm%20wdt%3AP570%20%3Fd%20%7D%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%21bound%28%3Fd%29%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%20FILTER%20%28%21regex%28%3FgivennameLabel%2C%22%28e%7Ci%7Cu%29%22%29%29.%0A%20%20%23%20FILTER%20%28STRLEN%28%3FgivennameLabel%29%20%3D%206%29%0A%7D%20%23%20Order%20by%20%20%0ALIMIT%2050)

I think something like this should work, although it's not working out.

```sql
BIND(STRLEN(str(?givennameLabel)) as ?NL)
FILTER (?NL = 6)
```

Comment: HAVING is to filter results after a GROUP BY. FILTER is correct. Does the query return results **without both** (regex and strlen) filters? And if yes, with only one of those filters.

Comment: Yes, Once both lines are commented out the query returns the expected results. No results are returned if either of the filters are applied. I'm also testing the number of characters in the line _(STRLEN(?givennameLabel)AS ?Namechars)_

Comment: The problem is that `givennameLabel` is not bound...I don't see any triple pattern with it, just the filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think found the problem: It looks like you call some "magic" SERVICE which creates some variable `givennameLabel`. For me sounds strange, but that might lead to the fact that the variable is not bound it time of filtering. If you put the whole query in a sub-select, it works:

```sql
#Male artists
SELECT * WHERE {

     {
     SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?givennameLabel (STRLEN(?givennameLabel)AS ?Namechars)
       ?mLabel ?plLabel WHERE {
       ?m wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
       ?m wdt:P21 wd:Q6581097.
       ?m wdt:P735 ?givenname.
       ?m wdt:P27 ?pl.
       ?m (wdt:P106/wdt:P279*) wd:Q483501.
       OPTIONAL { ?m wdt:P175 ?performer. }
       OPTIONAL {?m wdt:P570 ?d } 
       FILTER (!bound(?d))
       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    } 
    LIMIT 50
    }
  FILTER (!regex(?givennameLabel,"(e|i|u)")).
  FILTER (STRLEN(?givennameLabel) = 6)       
}
```

### Update

The suggested query does only consider 50 resources and without the LIMIT leads to a timeout. As mentioned by user3240704,
an alternative solution is to avoid the `SERVICE` clause and use `rdfs:label` instead:

```sql
#Male artists
 SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?givennameLabel (STRLEN(?givennameLabel)AS ?Namechars) 
                 ?mLabel ?plLabel 
 WHERE {
   ?m wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
   ?m wdt:P21 wd:Q6581097.
   ?m wdt:P735 ?givenname.
   ?m wdt:P27 ?pl.
   ?m (wdt:P106/wdt:P279*) wd:Q483501.
   OPTIONAL { ?m wdt:P175 ?performer. }
   OPTIONAL {?m wdt:P570 ?d } 
   FILTER (!bound(?d))
   ?givenname rdfs:label ?label 
   FILTER(LANG(?label) ="en"). 
   FILTER (!regex(?label,"(e|i|u)")). 
   FILTER (STRLEN(?label) = 6)}
} 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I came across the "magic" SERVICE and it seemed to work but the query will probably time out if I expand the scope (comment out the LIMIT). 
I'll look into an alternative method using triple patterns as you mentioned, or binding the _givennameLabel_

Comment: I ended up binding the ?label which expands the scope 

`?givenname rdfs:label ?label FILTER(LANG(?label) ="en"). 
FILTER (!regex(?label,"(e|i|u)")).
FILTER (STRLEN(?label) = 6)`

Comment: Right, that might be the better solution to query for `rdfs:label` instead. I'm wondering what's behind the `wikibase:label` SERVICE and how it works. I'll check the documentation.

Comment: Ok, this is a label service with some nice features like language fallback and the like: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service

Comment: This was my first query on SparQL / Wiki data. I feel I understand much more now, thanks for the patience in answering.                                              TDLR: wikibase:label service acts as a dictionary, you can't query against it. Bind values if you wish to query the data